# How can I dockerize ASP.NET Core app and Redis together?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, redis, docker-compose

I'm working with a Docker and try to connect redis and web application. This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:  
  web:
    image: redistest:latest
    depends_on:
      - "redis_image"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9901:80"

  redis_image:
    image: redis
    container_name: cache
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

This is my ConnectionStrings:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "redis": "localhost:6379,abortConnect=False"
  },
```

Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore RedisTest.csproj

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish RedisTest.csproj -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RedisTest.dll"]
```

Connection to Redis in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDistributedRedisCache(option =>
{
    option.Configuration = Configuration.GetConnectionString("redis");
});
```

To connect to docker I write in cmd next commands:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

This commands work good, but after I go to "localhost:9901", I receive next errors in console

```
web_1          | fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
web_1          |       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
web_1          | StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this operation: EVAL; SocketFailure on localhost:6379/Subscription, origin: Error, input-buffer: 0, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, unanswered-write: 1291s ago, keep-alive: 60s, pending: 0, state: Connecting, last-heartbeat: never, last-mbeat: -1s ago, global: 0s ago ---> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: SocketFailure on localhost:6379/Subscription, origin: Error, input-buffer: 0, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, unanswered-write: 1291s ago, keep-alive: 60s, pending: 0, state: Connecting, last-heartbeat: never, last-mbeat: -1s ago, global: 0s ago
web_1          |    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

web_1          | fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
web_1          |       Connection id "0HLKGR00VUQLM", Request id "0HLKGR00VUQLM:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
web_1          | StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this operation: EVAL; SocketFailure on localhost:6379/Subscription, origin: Error, input-buffer: 0, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, unanswered-write: 1291s ago, keep-alive: 60s, pending: 0, state: Connecting, last-heartbeat: never, last-mbeat: -1s ago, global: 0s ago ---> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: SocketFailure on localhost:6379/Subscription, origin: Error, input-buffer: 0, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, unanswered-write: 1291s ago, keep-alive: 60s, pending: 0, state: Connecting, last-heartbeat: never, last-mbeat: -1s ago, global: 0s ago
web_1          |    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

How can I fix this problems? I don't know how to force ASP.NET Core app see Redis in Docker.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 2 things you need to change:

1: Docker-compose file should be updated and should have the Links for the container communication.

```
version: '3.7'

services:  
  web:
    image: redistest:latest
    depends_on:
      - "redis_image"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9901:80"
    links:
      - "redis_image"

  redis_image:
    image: redis
    container_name: cache
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

2: The ConnectionStrings should be updated. Instead of localhost use the service name of redis_image as below

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "redis": "redis_image:6379,abortConnect=False"
  },
```

Let me know the results